# WinSCP like program for MacOS with proxy support

Tags: macos, proxy, winscp

I was accessing to the deployment servers via WinSCP on my old Windows machine. Since I just have a proxy point on deployment site; WinSCP's proxy feature was excellent for me.

After I moved to Mac OS X I couldn't find an SFTP client like WinSCP which has the feature proxying.

Could you recommend one like WinSCP on Mac?

Comment: I guess you are better off on apple.SE with this kind of question. (Also, check out `Transmit`)

Comment: It is just my 3rd day with this machine. I don't give up that fast !

Answer (score 0):

Max OSX is a BSD-like operation system. Why don't you use the shell command?

Comment: you mean ? sftp from my server to the jumping server  from terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on scp and its functionality but I use [fetch](http://fetchsoftworks.com/) for a nice sftp gui and it works great for me.

Comment: is there any free analoque of “fetch”?